# Rails different params in create and update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, dry, strong-parameters

I have an `Event` model. And it has `budget` param. Business logic requires that `budget`, once set on creation, cannot be changed later. 
On client side this means that I disable corresponding field.

But of course, this data can still be sent to server manually. 
On server, prior setup was the following:

```
def event_params
  params
    .require(:event)
    .permit(
      :title,
      :budget,
      ...
    )
```

And `event_params` were used in both create and update methods. 
I was considering creating two distinct sets of permitted params for create and update, but I don't like this idea because DRY.

What would your suggestions on this question would be? How to prevent budget updating while keeping code elegant?

Answer (score 3):

As you've suggested, you could use two separate helpers `event_params_for_create` and `event_params_for_update`.

In order to DRY them up, you could try this:

```
def event_params_common
  [:generic_value_1, :generic_value_2]
end

def event_params_for_create
  event_params_preprocessed
    .require(:event)
    .permit(event_params_common.concat([:extra_create_only_param]))
end

def event_params_for_update
  event_params_preprocessed
    .require(:event)
    .permit(event_params_common)
end
```

You would then use the respective methods during create or update, for instance;

```
# def create
@event = Event.new(event_params_for_create)

# def update
@event.update(event_params_for_update)
```

In this way, you're only configuring your common fields once.

Answer (score 2):

If the `budget` can't be changed later, you can't allow the `:budget` on the params of an update action (eg: `@event.update(event_params)`). This is not a violation of DRY, it's a security matter of your site.

As an example, check how devise works. He has one set of parameters for `sign_up` and a different one for `account_update`
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L137

But if you want to use the same parameters for both create and update, you can move the business logic to a service. Here is a nice article about them: https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services

The idea is create an `EventService` with one method to create and other to update. Each method treats the allowed parameters received from your controller (from `event_params`)